# Get Table Name from prepared statement

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

I am thinking about designing a DB modify notification system.
For this purpose I was wondering if I can get required information by 
extending `PreparedStatement`?

For my purpose, I would like to get at least following of information:

1. Type of operation (select/insert/update)
2. Table name

Comment: What is a "DB modify notification system"? What does it do? What happens if somebody modifies the database using an SQL tool, not Java?

Comment: Externam modifications are beyond the scope of notification system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can get the table name from the following:

```
ResultSetMetaData resultSetMetaData = preparedStatement.getMetaData();        
System.out.println("Table name " + resultSetMetaData.getTableName(1)); 
//1 here is the first column of the table for which the operation is made.
```

Trying to figure out how can we get the operation performed.

We can manipulate the logic to see if it's select or insert or update and send notification with the operation and the retrieved table name from above step.

Comment: interesting approach, though the answer is incomplete